# Same words, arranged differently - is there a difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I refer specifically to

'Nothing is Impossible' as frequently used

vs

'Impossible is Nothing' a quote by Muhammed Ali - therefore no doubt a boast!

But is there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Only Yoda thinks "Impossible is Nothing" means "Nothing is Impossible."

"Nothing is Impossible" means that there is some chance of a thing happening even if you don't think it all likely. It is a double negation of "Anything is Possible". It can be meant seriously or sarcasticlly: 
    "Do you he will have unloaded the dishwasher?" 
    "Well - Nothing is impossible."

"Impossible is nothing" is a slightly contrived boast like "I laugh in the face of danger" that presumably is a play on "Nothing is Impossible".

"X is nothing to me" means X is trivial, easy, or insignificant. So sayingh "(The) Impossible is Nothing (to me)" is a boast that things other people think are impossible are routine, even trivial to you.

Or to give the last word to Douglas Adams (in an allusion to Alice in Wonderland):

> "If you've done 6 impossible things this morning, why not round 
>   it off with breakfast at Milliways, the Restaurant at the 
>   End of the Universe?”